Problems serving Vue Vite build through Express, Failed to load module script: Expected JavaScript module
I am currently trying to test my Nodejs (Vue, Vite, Express) web application in production but am having trouble serving specific routes to the client.
On some pages i recieve
Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
Any ideas would be appreciated!
my Vite builds my project in a topmost dist directory
I am using ejs so i can easily switch between production and development, my (stripped) indexhtmlejs file is as follows

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>

          <% if (environment === 'production') { %>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%= manifest['src/main.css'].file %>" />
          <% } %>

     </head>
    <body>
    <div id="app"></div>


     <% if (environment == "production") { %>
     <script type="module" src="<%= manifest['src/main.js'].file %>"></script>
     <% } else { %>
     <!-- this link may be @vite instead of @vite/client-->
     <script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/@vite/client"></script>
     <script type="module" src="http://localhost:5173/src/main.js"></script>
     <% } %>

     </body>
     </html>

and my (stripped) express server

import homepageRouter from "./homepage_router.js";
import apiRoutes from "./api_router.js";

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');


const distPath = path.join(path.resolve(), "dist");
app.use("/", express.static(distPath));

app.use('/', apiRoutes);
app.use('/', homepageRouter);

// set port, listen for requests
app.listen(process.env.PORT, () =>{
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
})    

and additionally my homepageRouter where i serve my parse my manifest

router.get("/*", async (_req, res) => {
  const data = {
    environment: 'production',
    manifest: await parseManifest('production'),
  };

  res.render("index.html.ejs", data);
});

const parseManifest = async (enviroment) => {
  if (enviroment != 'production') return {};

  const manifestPath = path.join(path.resolve(), "dist", "manifest.json");
  const manifestFile = await fs.readFile(manifestPath);

  return JSON.parse(manifestFile);
};

Something i've noticed is the website works with urls which are not nested
e.g.
/home
works fine
/access
works fine
/access/error
/access/login
results in the above error

Set the module setting in your package.json.

i already have
type: "module"
if that is the correct setting
